# How to get Active Directory CA certificate for my ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, certificate, ca

I know my AD server host&port, and I want to install on my ubuntu machine the CA certificate for the AD server.

How can I retrieve the CA certificate from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really no different than getting a certificate from a website, since the initial SSL handshake is exactly the same. You can use the answer from [here](https://superuser.com/a/176721/233663), but use the domain name and port 636 (the default port for LDAPS):

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:636 -showcerts
```

Replace "example.com" with your domain name.

Comment: I got both "Server certificate" and "certificate chain", what is the difference?

Comment: Can you even connect? Is there a firewall in the way? You can test with `telnet example.com 636` or, if you have `netcat` installed, `nc -zv example.com 636`

Comment: Edited my comment

Comment: The server certificate is the actual certificate used to encrypt the connection. The chain includes the root certificate and the intermediate certificate that your computer needs to trust to be able to trust the server certificate.

Comment: So if you install the root and intermediate certificates, you don't need to actually install the server certificate for it to be trusted.